# Renew autoref caption titles when using polyglossia

Tags: hyperref, captions, polyglossia

I am trying to renew autoref caption titles when using the polyglossia package. Newer versions should, according to the manual, support the \addto command similar to Babel. However, I am unable to get it to work as the following MWE illustrates.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=american]{english}

%\usepackage[american]{babel}

\makeatletter
 \addto\extrasamerican{
\renewcommand*{\sectionautorefname}{Section}    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Test}\label{sec:test}
Autoref to \autoref{sec:test} for a test.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command to append to in this case is `\blockextras@english`, not `\extrasamerican`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}

\makeatletter
\appto{\blockextras@english}{%
  \renewcommand*{\sectionautorefname}{Section}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Test}\label{sec:test}
Autoref to \autoref{sec:test} for a test.

\end{document}
```

Besides, if you don't plan to use `\autoref` with other languages, you can place the `\renewcommand` outside the `\appto` altogether.

Comment: I just see that you changed your answer from `\appto{\captionsenglish}`to `\blockextras@english`. What's the difference?

Comment: @Jörg: @egreg suggested that it is a more proper way semantically. Note that there is also a similar `\inlineextras@english` which will work inside `\foreignlanguage` or `otherlanguage*`.